# Filter dataframe on multiple column combinations in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataframe that I would like to subset based on the information in a different dataframe.

For example I have a df with different values for x,y, and z:

```
df <- expand.grid(x=1:5,y=10:12,z=c('a','b'))
```

from this df I would like to subset all values that have y=10 and z=a, or y=11 and z=a. The information I use for subsetting is in a dataframe:

```
filter_vector2 <- expand.grid(y=10:11,z='a')
> filter_vector2
   y z
1 10 a
2 11 a
```

When I would filter based on the contents on one column I would normally create a vector and use the %in% function:

```
filter_vector1 <- c(y=10,y=11)

filtered_data <-  df %>%
    filter(y %in% filter_vector1)
```

However, how can I apply the filter selection based on the combinations of columns in the filter_vector2?

Comment: Simply `merge` or `join` since both are actually data frames.

Comment: filtered_data <-  df %>%  inner_join(filter_vector2) did the trick!

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this in one line using `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
filtered_vector <- setDT(df)[which(paste0(y,z) %in% paste0(filter_vector1,filter_vector2$z)),]

filtered_vector
    x  y z
 1: 1 10 a
 2: 2 10 a
 3: 3 10 a
 4: 4 10 a
 5: 5 10 a
 6: 1 11 a
 7: 2 11 a
 8: 3 11 a
 9: 4 11 a
10: 5 11 a
```